# Want to make image as required field in aem touch UI

Tags: aem

I want to make image (fileUpload) as required field in AEM as Granite Validators are not working for fileUploads.

This widget doesn't provide me any required "true".
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried the steps in this article. Looks like an issue for validation is present in the app? http://experience-aem.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/aem-62-support-required-validator-on-file-upload-image-in-touch-ui-dialog.html

Comment: I have a dialog with two image-picker in different tabs.one is mendatory,one is not. How can i solve it then?

Comment: Can't you modularise the sample script and make it work with your field for individual case? I mean I have seen some JS similar to this in a project and think it's possible with JS coding. I will gist it if I can find it but it's down to JS organisation in the end.

Answer (score 1):

required(boolean)
Indicates if the field is mandatory to be filled.

Refer API : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload/index.html?highlight=granite%2Fui%2Fcomponents%2Ffoundation%2Fform%2Ffileupload#/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload

Comment: If you are using AEM 6.0 or 6.1 then "required : true" wont work as that property is not available in those versions.

Answer (score 0):

look at the [/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload/fileupload.jsp](http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload/fileupload.jsp)  which details about what are the supporting properties that granite widget is going to support. Example for your file upload the required (Boolean) property mentioned as shown below code snippet.

```
 /**
     * Indicates if the field is mandatory to be filled.
     */
    - required (Boolean)
```

and also adding the property, it works as expected when i have tested it in AEM6.2 as shown in below image.

[image: fileupload]

Comment: Hi Var, If i add required true,it give me error as u shown in the image,but if i add the image,it still shows error.Please test it properly and get back to me Var.

Comment: @ShivaniGarg we can always add a custom-validation and add **afteredit cq:listener**. Here is a good example :  https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-validate.html